# Is it possible downgrade from laravel 7 to laravel 5.8?

Tags: laravel

I need to do the same project but i need to downgrade the version from laravel 7.* to laravel 5.8 because in my project is required php 7.1 ( I know this is not good but my boss want to do for a client )

Thanks

Comment: https://medium.com/in-laravel/how-to-install-upgrade-or-downgrade-a-specific-version-of-laravel-717bb1ba9ae6

Comment: Well downgrading is basically the same as upgrading, but in the opposite direction. Downgrade your version requirements and  then check the [release notes](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/releases) for each version you're downgrading from to find out what features were added in that version and you need to rewrite

Answer (score 2):

it is easy to do

first backup your laravel 7 project

second fresh install laravel 5.* in your machine.

and then copy your app , resource , routes and packeage.json and then fire command

```
composer install
```

if any error than solve one by one